# What is the most pythonic way to exclude elements of a list that start with a specific character?

Tags: python, coding-style

I have a list of strings. I want to get a new list that excludes elements starting with '#' while preserving the order. What is the most pythonic way to this? (preferably not using a loop?)

Comment: Sounds like you want to exclude comments from a file. The answer in that case is "don't read them in in the first place".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
[x for x in my_list if not x.startswith('#')]
```

That's the most pythonic way of doing it. Any way of doing this will end up using a loop in either Python or C.

Answer (score 11):

Not using a loop? There is `filter` builtin:

```
filter(lambda s: not s.startswith('#'), somestrings)
```

Note that in Python 3 it returns iterable, not a list, and so you may have to wrap it with `list()`.

Comment: which one is more pythonic? using a loop or filter?

Comment: @MoZo list comprehensions are preferred over `filter`,`map`, etc. if paired with a `lambda`. `filter` might be better if you had something like `filter(str.isalpha, somestrings)`. This will also be slower than a list comp.

Comment: @MoZo I don't see much difference here. In this simple case, I'd go with a loop. But when predicate function is complicated, it's `filter` only.